# How do I fix "'module' object has no attribute 'required_version'" for "gi.require_version('Gtk', '3.0')"?

Tags: apt, python, gtk, python-2.7, glade

I'm working with some people to build a fake news detecting program and have made some great progress but out of 5 members of the group only 1 person can run the Python program. I am running a clean install of Ubuntu 16.04 that is only a few hours old and the person who can run the program has Fedora 26. The error I get when trying to run the program is:

```
conesco3@Conesco3:~/Documents/Alternative-News-Checker$ sudo python main.py
[sudo] password for conesco3: 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 6, in <module>
    gi.require_version('Gtk', '3.0')
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'require_version'
```

I went and installed gtk+-3.0 with:

```
sudo apt install gtk+-3.0
```

But that doesn't help.

I also installed Glade, which the UI part of the program is made with, to try and fix it. But that did not make this error go away either.

[The files can be found here](https://github.com/WeMightNotHaveTheGuts/Alternative-News-Checker) if you want to try and recreate the problem, I am stumped so any help is appreciated and I have tried several other suggestions for fixes like installing `python-gobject` and they haven't fixed the problem.

I can run a smaller-scale program and get the same error ([screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cHBpX.png)). This program is sufficient to produce the problem:

```python
import gi
gi.require_version("Gtk", "3.0")
from gi.repository import Gtk

window = Gtk.Window(title="Hello World")
window.show()
window.connect("delete-event", Gtk.main_quit)
Gtk.main()
```

Running that simplified program looks like this:

```
conesco3@Conesco3:~$ cd Desktop/
conesco3@Conesco3:~/Desktop$ python2 hello.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "hello.py", line 2, in <module>
    gi.require_version("Gtk", "3.0")
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'require_version'
conesco3@Conesco3:~/Desktop$
```

EDIT: After suggestions made by someone else I created a virtual environment and piped the requirements from the Fedora computer into a txt file and in the virtual environment install them again; this gives the same error.

The output of `python2 -c 'import gi; print(gi.__file__)'` is:

```
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gi/__init__.pyc
```

Comment: What's the output of  `python2 -c 'import gi; print(gi.__file__)'` ?

Comment: @FlorianDiesch This returns: /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gi/__init__.pyc

Comment: That's not Ubuntu's GI package but something you installed manually. It's either a very old version or something different that just happened to be called `gi`, too. Try to remove it and make sure the package `python-gi` is installed.

Comment: You are a life saver, at a 2 day hackathon and not been able to run the program for the past few hours. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `gi` module you are importing isn't the one from Ubuntu's GI package `python-gi` but something you installed manually in `/usr/local/`. It's either a very old version or something different that just happened to be called `gi`, too.

Remove it and make sure the package `python-gi` is installed.